# Index doesn't improve performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, query-performance

I have a simple table structure in my postgres database:

```
CREATE TABLE device
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  version bigint NOT NULL,
  device_id character varying(255),
  date_created timestamp without time zone,
  last_updated timestamp without time zone,
  CONSTRAINT device_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
)
```

I'm often querying data based on deviceId column. The table has 3,5 million rows, so it leads to performance issues:

```
"Seq Scan on device  (cost=0.00..71792.70 rows=109 width=8) (actual time=352.725..353.445 rows=2 loops=1)"
"  Filter: ((device_id)::text = '352184052470420'::text)"
"Total runtime: 353.463 ms"
```

Hence I've created index on device_id column:

```
CREATE INDEX device_device_id_idx
  ON device
  USING btree
  (device_id );
```

However my problem is, that database still uses sequential scan, not index scan. The query plan after creating the index is the same:

```
"Seq Scan on device  (cost=0.00..71786.33 rows=109 width=8) (actual time=347.133..347.508 rows=2 loops=1)"
"  Filter: ((device_id)::text = '352184052470420'::text)"
"Total runtime: 347.538 ms"
```

The result of the query are 2 rows, so I'm not selecting a big portion of the table. I don't really understand why index is disregarded. What can I do to improve the performance?

*edit:*

My query:

```
select id from device where device_id ='357560051102491A';
```

I've run `analyse` on the device table, which didn't help

device_id contains also characters.

Comment: Edit your question and include the query.

Comment: Out of interest, why is `deviceid` a `varchar` if it's numeric?

Comment: Try to update statistics on your table. It looks like postgres has outdated statistics on this particular table.

Comment: Added the query. DeviceId is not numeric. I've run analyse after I've created the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, like time resolves everything. I'm not sure what have happened, but currently its working fine.
From the time I've posted this question I didn't change anything  and now I get this query plan:

```
"Bitmap Heap Scan on device  (cost=5.49..426.77 rows=110 width=166)"
"  Recheck Cond: ((device_id)::text = '357560051102491'::text)"
"  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on device_device_id_idx  (cost=0.00..5.46 rows=110 width=0)"
"        Index Cond: ((device_id)::text = '357560051102491'::text)"
```

Time breakdown (timezone GMT+2):

- ~15:50 I've created the index
- ~16:00 I've dropepd and recreated the index several times, since it was not working
- 16:05 I've run `analyse device` (didn't help)
- 16:44:49 from app server request_log, I can see that the requests executing the query are still taking around **500 ms**
- 16:56:59 I can see first request, which takes **23 ms** (the index started to work!)

The question stays, why it took around 1:10 hour for the index to be applied? When I was creating indexes in the same database few days ago the changes were immediate.

Comment: Maybe `the app` was reusing a prepared query and/or was still within a transaction? -->> check the logs if you want to know.

Comment: Nope, I was executing the query and also the query plan also manually from pgAdmin

Answer (score 0):

You may need to look at the queries. To use an index, the queries need to be sargable. That means certain ways to construct the queries are better than other ways. I am not familiar with Postgre but in SQl Server this would include such things (very small sample of the bad constructs):

- Not doing data transformations in the join - instead store the data
  properly
- Not using correlated subqueries - use derived tables or temp table
  instead
- Not using OR conditions - use UNION ALL instead

Your first step shoud be to get a good book on performance tuning for your specific database. It will talk about what constructions to avoid for your particular database engine.

Comment: I've added the query to my question. My query is trivial and it selects 2 rows from 3,5 million table.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are not used when you cast a column to a different type:

```
((device_id)::text = '352184052470420'::text)
```

Instead, you can do this way:

```
(device_id = ('352184052470420'::character varying))
```

(or maybe you can change device_id to TEXT in the original table, if you wish.)

Also, remember to run `analyze device` after index has been created, or it will not be used anyway.

Comment: This was not an issue, as you can see from the query I'm not doing any type casts. And now everything works fine with the same query.